# Solutions to Alan Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology"

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

Does anyone know where I can find (if they exist) full solutions to the exercises of Alan Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried googling for them? I don't think this is a great question for the site... but maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 22):

This should probably be a comment, but I felt was too long. I'm sure searching "allen hatcher solutions" is about the best you can do with google. But look at this quote from Hatcher's personal website:

> I have not written up solutions to the exercises. The main reason for this is that the book is used as a textbook at a number of universities where the problems sets count for part of a student's grade (that is how I teach the course for example). However, individuals who are studying the book on their own and would like hints for specific problems should feel free to email me and I will try to respond.

[His homepage](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/) lists his email address, so if you're interested in working through his book, I have a feeling he'd be glad to answer your questions.